# Calculating radius of circle based on 2 points on circle

Tags: circles

Im trying to find radius of given circle below and its center coordinates. Base circle is unit circle with radius 1 as well as coordinates for p1 and p2 are given beforehand

[image]

Up to this point I know that
$$
|p_1 - c| = r
$$

$$
|p_2 - c| = r
$$

$$
r^2 + 1 = c^2
$$

But somehow I got stuck to solve and figure out radius and center points of circle. Is there any thing am I missing?

Comment: What exactly are you given? What you call the base circle seems to be the unit circle centered at the origin, but apart from that it's a bit unclear. Are you given the coordinates of $p_1$ and $c$, for instance?

Comment: I edited question. Coordinates for p1 and p2 are given only, Need to find radius and coordinates for c

Answer (score 1):

This is how I read the problem: there are 2 arbitrary points M and N with their Cartesian coordinates inside the circle $w$, find the circle $\alpha $ , including points M,N and radius $r$. There are 2 ways of problem's solution: geometrical and analytical.

1. Geometrical method.
   [image]

The circles $w$ and $\alpha $ are called orthogonal.
We need to inverse one of a given point relative to  $w$, e.g. point$N$, and $N'$ is an inverse image of $N$. The construct of $N'$ is marked green. The circle $\alpha $ including $M$, $N$ and $N'$ is orthogonal to the base circle $w$ in conformance with inversion feature.

2. Analytical method.

$\alpha $: $(x-xp)^2+(y-yp)^2=r^2$

Let us construct 3 equations in Cartesian coordinates having 3 variables $xp, yp, r$:

1) $(xm-xp)^2+(ym-yp)^2=r^2$

2) $(xn-xp)^2+(yn-yp)^2=r^2$

3) $ r^2+1=xp^2+yp^2$

Thus, there are 3 quadratic equations, which can be easily solved for  3 required variables $xp, yp, r$.

Comment: What's wrong? What do you mean? The equation seems to be correct. It specifies the orthogonality of circles.